# return true from javascript then form continue to submit

Tags: javascript

i have php page and javascript, the page is contact us form and before submit button there is captcha  when form submit it checks captcha if it validate return true else alert and create again captcha but it doesn't work when it return true after that nothing happen

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
<form action="" id="demo-form" onsubmit="validateCaptcha()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <h3>Quick Contact</h3>
    <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
      <input placeholder="Your name" name="name" id="name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus><br>

      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" id="mail" type="email" tabindex="2" required><br>

      <input placeholder="Subject" id="sub" name="subject" type="text" tabindex="3" required><br>

      <input placeholder="Mobile Number" name="number" pattern="^((\+92)|(0092)|(0))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$" id="contactInformation" type="tel" tabindex="4" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter mobile number like: 03001234567')"
      oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" > <br>
      <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." tabindex="6" name="message" id="msg" tabindex="5" required></textarea><br>
      <div id="captcha">
    </div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Captcha Code Here" id="cpatchaTextBox"/><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="7" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" /><br>
        <button type="reset" name="reset" tabindex="8" id="contact-reset">Clear Form</button>
 </form>
<?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $subject=$_REQUEST['subject'];
    $number=$_REQUEST['number'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($subject=="")||($number=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
    else{        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $msg= "Name: ".$name."\nContact Number: ".$number."\n".$message ;
        mail("xyz@gmail.com", $subject, $msg , $from);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'alert("EMAIL SENT..!");',
        'setTimeout(function(){',
          ' window.location.href = "thanks.php";',
        ' }, 50);',
        '</script>'
;
        }
    }  
?>

</div>
            </section>

               </div>
    <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
// JavaScript Document
var code;
function createCaptcha() {
  //clear the contents of captcha div first 
  document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "";
  var charsArray =
  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@!#$%^&*";
  var lengthOtp = 6;
  var captcha = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lengthOtp; i++) {
    //below code will not allow Repetition of Characters
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * charsArray.length + 1); //get the next character from the array
    if (captcha.indexOf(charsArray[index]) == -1)
      captcha.push(charsArray[index]);
    else i--;
  }
  var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
  canv.id = "captcha";
  canv.width = 100;
  canv.height = 50;
  var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "25px Georgia";
  ctx.strokeText(captcha.join(""), 0, 30);
  //storing captcha so that can validate you can save it somewhere else according to your specific requirements
  code = captcha.join("");
  document.getElementById("captcha").appendChild(canv); // adds the canvas to the body element
}
function validateCaptcha() {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (document.getElementById("cpatchaTextBox").value == code) {
    return true;
  }else{
    alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
    createCaptcha();
  }
}
```

kindly if anyone can do that for me i just want, when captcha validate the form submit and email sent to the person.

Comment: `<form action="" id="demo-form" onsubmit="return validateCaptcha()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`
you have missed the return in form onsubmit when validating the form your should return either true or false

Comment: If you create and validate captcha on the client side, you don't worry about the validation. Because, all attackers can access to your captcha value by "code" variable or window["code"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this, one of the simpler solution is to cast `event.preventDefault()` only when needed.
**No need to return anything.**

```
function validateCaptcha() {
  if (document.getElementById("cpatchaTextBox").value != code) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
    createCaptcha();
  }
}
```

**WORKING DEMO CAPTCHA OK**

```js
function validateCaptcha() {
  const captchaMock = false; // switch true/false to see the behavior
  if (captchaMock) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
    createCaptcha();
  }
}

function createCaptcha() {
  alert('New captcha');
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="validateCaptcha()">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**WORKING DEMO CAPTCHA NOT OK**

```js
function validateCaptcha() {
  const captchaMock = true; // switch true/false to see the behavior
  if (captchaMock) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
    createCaptcha();
  }
}

function createCaptcha() {
  alert('New captcha');
}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="validateCaptcha()">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Look at my working snippet, switch from true to false to see the behavior of the submit.

Comment: yes it worked for me now you explained well and i understand
my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

```
 onsubmit="validateCaptcha()"
```

should be

```
 onsubmit="return validateCaptcha()"
```

to prevent the return value of `validateCaptcha` being thrown away. In addition, `validateCaptcha` needs to return boolean `false` to prevent form submission - *returning some other falsey value such as `undefined` doesn't work.*

You can also pass the event object to the validation routine using

```
onsubmit="return validateCaptcha( event)"
```

which allows cancelling the event in the validation routine using event methods called on the event argument.

However, adding event handlers in HTML is error-prone, and adding submit event handlers to the form in JavaScript using

```
formObject.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler, true);
```

may be preferable - the submit handler gets called with `event` as its argument.